# Simple temporary filesystem for Python

Tags: python, filesystems

Currently, I have the following code using `FPDF` and `Pillow`:

```
pdf = create_pdf_with_FPDF()
img = create_img_with_pillow()
img.save(temporary_location)
pdf.image(temporary_location, x, y)
```

The first two lines are fine, but I'm not very happy that I have to store the `img` on my harddisk just in order to load it again in the next line.

**Is there a way to set up a temporary filesystem that is forgotten as soon as the program ends? (On a Mac)**

Comment: Have you considered the [`tempfile`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tempfile.html) module?

Answer (score 1):

Hope this might help you.

```
import tempfile

pdf = create_pdf_with_FPDF()
img = create_img_with_pillow()
temp_file = tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile(delete=False, suffix='.jpg')
temporary_location = temp_file.name
img.save(temporary_location)
pdf.image(temporary_location, x, y)
```